# Mean free path for $3\rightarrow 1$ scattering

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, neutrinos, phase-space, mean-free-path

I want to calculate the mean free path of an antineutrino in nuclear matter where it can undergo the reaction $p+e^-+\bar{\nu} \rightarrow n$, which I imagine will involve calculating the rate of that process.  I have never seen the phase space calculation of a $3\rightarrow 1$ process before.  Also, I have only seen the mean free path calculated for a neutrino scattering off of one particle (like $n+\nu \rightarrow p + e^-$), not scattering off of two particles.

Does anyone have a reference or suggestion for this type of calculation?

Comment: There is no way one can set up such an experiment with three free particles to interact within the heisenberg  uncertainty principle volume.  So you are asking for an antineutrino +hydrogen scattering generating a neutron  with the weak interaction.

Comment: This reaction should be able to happen (perhaps at a small rate) in a system with hot nuclear matter that traps neutrinos like a protoneutron star or neutron star merger.  In beta equilibrium, when there are neutron, proton, electron, and neutrino (or antineutrino) Fermi seas, then $n\rightarrow p + e^- + \bar{\nu}$ at the same rate as the reverse, $p + e^- + \bar{\nu} \rightarrow n$.  I'm just asking for how one would mathematically write down such a rate.

Comment: This inverse reaction must go as with inverse beta decay, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_beta_decay . Do you have a link for your suggestion that the exact reverse exists in stars?

Comment: That's the question I am looking at.  The reaction $e^- + p + \bar{\nu} \rightarrow n$ is suppressed because of the three particle initial state.  The reaction $p + \bar{\nu} \rightarrow n + e^+$ is suppressed by Pauli blocking, since the electron chemical potential in a neutron star is perhaps 200 MeV, so the rate would be suppressed by exp(-200 MeV / T) (T could be as high as 10 MeV).  So I am trying to determine which reaction is suppressed more, but I would need to know the phase space for 3 to 1 scattering.

Comment: it is not possible to have 3 to 1 scattering, afaik

Comment: see http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~bds10/aqp/lec20-21_compressed.pdf